# How to use multiple criteria in a Select Case in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to modify the following select case to use the values in G11 and G13 to place a value in C17, as well as a value in A17.  It currently just uses G11 to put a value in A17.  How can I modify it to also look at G13 and place a value in C17?

For example, if the value in G11 is between .01 and 4999.99, and the value in G13 is "Inspector", then the value in C17 is "100".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("G11")

        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

            Select Case Range("G11").Value
                Case Is < 0.01
                    Range("A17").Value = ""
                Case 0.01 To 4999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$0 - $4,999.99"
                Case 5000 To 9999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$5,000 - $9,999.99"
                Case 10000 To 19999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$10,000 - $19,999.99"
                Case 20000 To 34999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$20,000 - $34,999.99"
                Case 35000 To 49999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$35,000 - $49,999.99"
                Case 50000 To 99999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$50,000 - $99,999.99"
                Case 100000 To 149999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$100,000 - $149,999.99"
                Case 150000 To 199999.99
                    Range("A17").Value = "$150,000 - $199,999.99"
                Case Is >= 200000
                    Range("A17").Value = "$200,000 and up"
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Select Case` doesn't allow for multiple values like what you're looking to accomplish - You would have to either use multiple `If` statements or nest a second `If` / `Select Case` within each case... **But**, for something this simple, why not do it within Excel itself? - This seems like something you could use lookup tables for pretty well...

Comment: @JohnBustos while that is technically true, one could use `Select Case True` then `Case Range("G11")>.01 and Range("G11")<4999.99 and Range("G13") = "Inspector"`

Comment: Thanks.  I've used lookup tables for this in the past, I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something with Select Case.

Comment: Nice workaround, @ScottCraner! - Basically the same as If's, but it is a cool way to do it too!

Comment: Excellent @ScottCraner!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment

```
Select Case True
    Case Range("G11")>.01 and Range("G11")<4999.99 and Range("G13") = "Inspector"
        *Do your code*
   ...
```

By putting the Select Case as true, then in the Case lines you can use the `And` and `Or` operators.

But as you can see this then becomes a IF/ElseIF/Else situation.